# Checking conditionals

Tags: theme-development, loop, conditional-content

We all know about the default WordPress post types, these being aside, gallery, status, chat and so on. any good theme should support all of them.

In the case where a theme does support all of them, is it best, from a clean programming standard to do if, elseif, else if, else or should I use a switch case when checking if you are on a specific post type.

for example:

```
    if(is_aside()){

            }elseif(is_status()){

            }elseif(is_quote()){

            }elseif(is_link()){

            }elseif(is_chat()){

            }elseif(is_gallery()){

            }elseif(is_image()){

            }elseif(is_chat()){

            }elseif(is_video()){

            }elseif(is_audio()){

            }else{
                $this->_title($this->_options);
                $this->_author_and_date();
                $this->_thumbnail($this->_options);

                the_content();                  
            }
```

Seems messy and unclean, what would you suggest to do?

**note:** some conditionals may be wrong, this is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`get_post_format()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format) to build a conditional (or switch).

```
$format = get_post_format();

if ( 'status' == $format ) {
    //
} 
else if ( 'quote' == $format ) {
    //
}
// etc.
else {
    // get_post_format() returns FALSE for "standard"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Program-flow-wise, it won't make a lot of a difference. One good thing to observe is:

> If using `if-else`, its always recommended to put **frequently used `if` condition** at the top of `if-else` ladder

A `switch case` construction may aid legibility, but not always, depending how complex the conditions are.